# Java MySQL connection regularly times out

Tags: java, mysql, timeout

I connect to my database and I have timeouts on a regular basis. I have no idea how to proceed. Can anyone help me?

Attached is my code how I make the connection:

```
    private static Connection connection;

    public static boolean isConnected() {
        return (connection == null ? false : true);
    }

    public static void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        if (!isConnected()) {

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                connection = getConnection();
                System.out.println("Datenbank verbunden!");
            } catch (SQLException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void disconnect() {
        if (isConnected()) {
            try {
                connection.close();
                System.out.println("Datenbank entbunden!");
            } catch (SQLException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?connectTimeout=5000&socketTimeout=30000", user, password);

        // Here you can add a validation step to check if the connection is still valid.
        if (!connection.isValid(5)) { // 5 seconds timeout
            System.out.println("Datenbank Verbindung verloren!");
            connection.close();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?connectTimeout=5000&socketTimeout=30000", user, password);
            System.out.println("Datenbank Verbindung wiederhergestellt!");
        }

        return connection;
    }
```

I have already tried with timers that periodically re-establish the connection but nothing works.

Comment: usually this is a sign of slow queries, you can enable the slow query log and see if something needs longer than 30 seconds

Comment: Also consider the my.cnf configuration for your mysql server. Does it for instance have a timeout value on inactivity.

Comment: Seems like `getConnection()` should be a private method.  Maybe some code is using that method instead of the `connect()` method?  What does `isConnected()` do?  Please update with some code that shows how this class is used.

Comment: Also, the code is not thread safe.  is the app single threaded?

Comment: The whole pattern is wrong. `Connections` should not be static objects. You should get a `Connection` when you need one, inside the method that's going to execute the query or update, and close it automatically via a ty-with-resources statement; and you should use a connection pool like Apache DBCP to conserve connect events. The connection pool will take care of whether the pooled connection is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the additional parameter **autoReconnect=true** in your jdbc url.

Another option is a thread which just run 'select 1' every few seconds. It's like a ping on to the database.